# Let $a,b\in\Bbb R$ and $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ be defined by $f(x)=a\cos(|x^3-x|)+b|x|\sin(|x^3+x|)$.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Let $a,b\in\Bbb  R$ and $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ be defined by $f(x)=a\cos(|x^3-x|)+b|x|\sin(|x^3+x|)$. Then check the differentiability of $f(x)$ for following parts:-

i) At $x=0$ when $a=0,b=1$

ii) At $x=1$ when $a=1,b=0$

iii) At $x=0$ when $a=1,b=0$

iv) At $x=1$ when $a=1,b=1$

My attempt is as follows:-

As $\cos x$ itself is an even function

$$f(x)=a\cos(x^3-x)+b|x|\sin(|x^3+x|)$$

$$x^3+x\ge0$$
$$x(x^2+1)\ge0$$
$$x\ge0$$

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
    a\cos(x^3-x)+bx\sin(x^3+x), &x\ge0\\
    a\cos(x^3-x)+b(-x)\sin(-x^3-x), &x<0
  \end{cases}$$

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
    a\cos(x^3-x)+bx\sin(x^3+x), &x\ge0\\
    a\cos(x^3-x)+b(-x)\sin(-x^3-x), &x<0
  \end{cases}$$

Both branches came out to be same:-

$$f(x)=a\cos(x^3-x)+bx\sin(x^3+x)$$

Now this function seems to be always continuous and differentiable.

But actual answer is following:-

i) Not differentiable at $x=0$ when $a=0,b=1$

For other parts, it is differentiable.

What am I missing here? Any inputs?

Comment: It becomes |x|sin(| x^3 + x |) in part 1, which is differentiable at x = 0. Also, the function is differentiable in all parts, with f'x = 0.

Comment: Can you double-check your computation? I mean the branching part. It is not correct.

Comment: first branch is already in the simplified state and in second branch, $\sin(-x^3-x)$ will come as $-\sin(x^3+x)$ because $\sin x$ is an odd function and minus sign will cancel out with the $-$ sign of $x$. Here I think there is no error in computation. Can you indicate the exact place where you feel the computation error?

Comment: @MikeKarter, yes the resulting function is differentiable everywhere but it is contradicting actual answer.